# Given an array of n bits, how to generate every permutation with i 1's and n-i 0's?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

It's simple enough to brute force a collection of strings and then filter for every occurrence with the required count of 1's.

As n increases the number of possible permutations becomes very large, very quickly, however, and due to speed and space considerations, I'm trying to find a more sophisticated method -- ideally, one that doesn't involve excessive string processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can slice up the problem in subprocess (pseudocode):

```
array[] GetArrays(j, n)
    if(n = 0)
        return one empty array
    if(j = 0)
        return one array of n zeroes
    array[] zero = map(prepend 0,  GetArrays(j, n-1)) 
    array[] one = map(prepend 1,  GetArrays(j - 1, n - 1))
    return concat(zero, one)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick an arbitrary algorithm for generating all **combinations** of i elements from n. See this [former SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n), for example, or the 75 examples in different programming languages at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations). Then use it to generate all combinations of i elements from the set `{0,1,2,...,n-1}` and assign each result R=`(r1,r2,...,r_i)` a string of length n of zeros and ones where the positions of the ones are the values in R.